# Use Different Package Source to Develop vs Deploy with Poetry

Tags: python-poetry

When using Poetry, what is the best practice to allow for using a local, editable version of a package when developing locally, and a published version of a package in a repo when deploying?

I'm working on a project that uses a self developed python package, and poetry for dependency management. When developing locally, I want to use a local version of the package installed with the `--editable` flag so that I can easily make changes. However, when I deploy the project, I want to install the package from a privately managed repo.

At the moment, I can seem to do one or the other. I've set up two optional dependency groups, `private` and `local-private`, and included a supplemental source for the private repo. My `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```
[tool.poetry.group.local-private]
optional = true

[tool.poetry.group.local-private.dependencies]
my-package = {path = "../my-package"}


[tool.poetry.group.private]
optional = true

[tool.poetry.group.private.dependencies]
my-package = {version = "^0.2.0", source = "private_repo"}


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "private_repo"
url = "https://myprivaterepo.com"
priority = "supplemental"


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "PyPI"
priority = "primary"
```

However, it seems that because these packages share the same name, they get one entry in the `poetry.lock` file. As a result, when I install either group, `my-package` is pulled from the same source for both.

I understand that poetry resolves all dependencies, regardless of whether they're in an optional group or not. But is there a way to specify two different sources for a package or am I going about this entirely wrong?

**Edit / Workaround:**
The workaround, that's not really a proper workaround, that I ended up with is installing the local package separately with pip. So my `pyproject.toml` file looks like this:

```
[tool.poetry.group.private]
optional = true

[tool.poetry.group.private.dependencies]
my-package = {version = "^0.2.0", source = "private_repo"}


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "private_repo"
url = "https://myprivaterepo.com"
priority = "supplemental"


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "PyPI"
priority = "primary"
```

And then I have a separate `private-requirements.txt` file like this:

```
-e ../my-local-package
```

When installing locally, I run `poetry install` and then `pip install -r private-requirements.txt`. When installing during deployment, I run `poetry install --with private`.

This isn't truly a fix because poetry won't locally resolve the dependencies between `my-local-package` and the rest of my packages. Besides this potential pitfall, this works.

Comment: Have you tried the `dev` dependency group?

Comment: @sinoroc I just tried and same thing unfortunately. In the `poetry.lock`, there is one source with the directory to the local package.

Comment: Something like this used to work before the introduction of dependency groups, when there was only `dev`, but it was not documented or an officially supported technique.